# What are the factors affecting Boiling Point in Ions?

Tags: bond, ions, boiling-point

I understand that for molecular substances, intermolecular forces such as van der Waals forces and hydrogen bonding are the major factors effecting the boiling point.

However, I am not sure about what factors effect the boiling point in Ionic substances.  I assume it is to do with the strength of the bonds between ionic units, but then what effects this strength?

Thanks for your time!